# Add images and a mouseover event in a loop, in a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, dom, loops, greasemonkey, addeventlistener

I am using Greasemonkey and JavaScript to modify a page. I have found all the external links and added a image before links, I want to  add a mouseover event on images. I don't know how to do that in the loop. Here is what I have:

```
var anchors = document.evaluate('//a[@target]',document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
var icon4 = document.createElement('img');
icon4.src = '...'; 
for (var a = 0; a < anchors.snapshotLength; a++){
  if (anchors.snapshotItem(a).href.substring(0,16) != location.href.substring(0,16)){
    icon4.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){this.title = 'Hello'}, false);
    icon4.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){this.title = ''}, false);
    anchors.snapshotItem(a).parentNode.insertBefore(icon4.cloneNode(true),anchors.snapshotItem(a));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use anonymous functions in a loop like that. That leads to memory and performance problems.

Anyway, use [the return value of `insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore). like so:

```
var anchors = document.evaluate (
    '//a[@target]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
);
var icon4   = document.createElement('img');
icon4.src   = '...';

for (var a = 0; a < anchors.snapshotLength; a++) {
    if (anchors.snapshotItem(a).href.substring(0, 16) != location.href.substring(0, 16)) {
        var newNode = anchors.snapshotItem(a).parentNode.insertBefore (
            icon4.cloneNode (true), anchors.snapshotItem (a) 
        );

        newNode.addEventListener ('mouseover', myMouseInOutHandler, false);
        newNode.addEventListener ('mouseout',  myMouseInOutHandler, false);
    }
}

function myMouseInOutHandler (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.type == "mouseover") {
        zEvent.target.title = 'Hello';
    }
    else if (zEvent.type == "mouseout") {
        zEvent.target.title = '';
    }
}
```